# Connect to mongo db from ec2 instance with ip whitelist

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hey I have mongo db Atlas and EC2 server deployed via beanstalk. I would like to have better security with whitelisting only specific IP's that can connect to mongo. Problem is when I log into AWS console, and take **IPv4 Public IP** from my EC2 insance and whitelist that ip in mongo settings , then connection gets refused, when I whitelist all range of ip's then it is working, so It tells me that the IP is somehow wrong. What I am missing here folks ???

Comment: The more "proper" way to connect to you instance is connecting both VPC's so there's no need for "outside" traffic, assuming this is the way it's configured try whitelisting the EC2 instance VPC ip address.

Comment: it's available only for more expensive instances, I am assuming your talkina bout network peering